# Evaluate the contour integral

Tags: contour-integration, complex-integration

How to evaluate this,
$$\oint_{c} \frac{\sin\pi z^2+\cos\pi z^2}{(z-1)(z-2)}dz$$
where $C$ is the circle, $|z|=3$

I tried below things

I believe 1 and 2 are simple poles here and the equation can be reduced to $\frac{1}{z-1}+\frac{1}{z-2}$

How to continue from here? I am a beginner in contour integration, Any hints approach would be good.

Comment: Do you know Cauchy's formula? Yes, use partial fraction decomposition and Cauchy's formula.

Comment: You really really don't need partial fractions, just evaluate $(z-1)f(z)$ at $z=1$ and $(z-2)f(z)$ at $z=2$... @PedroTamaroff

Comment: @ThomasAndrews True, I still think partial fractions clear things up.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: Solving with Cauchy's formula, I get ZERO as my final answer... I'm just curious about |z|=3 in the question. What does that signify??

Comment: How did you evaluate the integral if you don't know what $|z|=3$ is? It means the set $\{z:|z|=3\}$ i.e. a circle with center $0$ and radius $3$.

Comment: @user2810706, remember the singularities are interior to your loop, no exterior.

Comment: @Nameless: So you mean to say that if in case, in the above integral I have (z-4) instead of (z-2) then the singularity will be exterior to |z|=3 and I can't consider that?

Comment: @Nameless: Cool... Got it.. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\;C_1\,,\,\,C_2\;$ be little circles around $\;1,2\;$ resp. By Cauchy's Theorem:

$$\oint_{C_1}\frac{\sin\pi z^2+\cos\pi z^2}{(z-1)(z-2)}dz=\oint_{C_1}\frac{\frac{\sin\pi z^2+\cos\pi z^2}{z-2}}{z-1}dz=\left.2\pi i\frac{\sin\pi z^2+\cos\pi z^2}{z-2}\right|_{z=1}=$$

$$=-2\pi i \left(0-1\right)=2\pi i $$

Do now something similar with $\;C_2\;$ and check that your integral is the sum of these two integrals.

Comment: $$\oint_{C_2}\frac{\sin\pi z^2+\cos\pi z^2}{(z-1)(z-2)}dz=\oint_{C_2}\frac{\frac{\sin\pi z^2+\cos\pi z^2}{z-1}}{z-2}dz=\left.2\pi i\frac{\sin\pi z^2+\cos\pi z^2}{z-1}\right|_{z=2}=$$


$$=2\pi i \left(0+1\right)=2\pi i $$


Hence the total sum is,
$4\pi i$

Comment: Yep, that's right